# Can't resolve symbol MenuItemCompat

Tags: android, menuitem

I get an error on using `MenuItemCompat` that the `symbol cannot be resolved`. Neither is there any option to import anything at all. I am new to android. I think there are some dependencies missing. I was trying to use `getActionProvider()` method to get Action Provider of a menu item.

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio then configure the SDK Manager and download below libraries (present inside Extras directory) -
1. Android Support Repository
2. Android Support Library

Then restart the Android Studio. If this doesn't work then update your Android Studio (latest is 1.3.1).

Comment: I have installed both libraries. Android version is 1.3.2. Not working in my case