# Error:(133, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable MenuItemCompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting following error when try to use "MenuItemCompat", Screenshot is attached

```
Error:(133, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable MenuItemCompat.
```

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2

[image]

**SDK plateforms and SDK Tools screenshot**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149773/gradle-and-android-v7-compat-issue

Comment: I deleted android sdk old folder. Installed it again via android studio 1.3.2. Still not working. I've also confirmed android location path in android studio(Build > Editbuild -> android location). It is same as installed. I've also confirmed android location path in "local.properties" file in Gradle scripts. It points to same folder. Any suggestion?

Comment: Solution in this url is also not working for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205567/cant-resolve-symbol-menuitemcompat